# html- как изменить "цель" для скроллинга

Tags: html, html5

Есть на сайте лента новостей. При скроллинге она двигается, тут все нормально. Недавно сделал так, что есть возможность раскрыть новость, т.е. в самом конце    `<body>` поверх всей страницы добавляется черный полупрозрачный `<div>` элемент, на нем располагается белая панель на которой размещаются изображения и текст. В общем как в вк. Проблема в следующем: эта панель не всегда влезает в экран, а при скроллинге двигается лента новостей. Как сделать так, чтобы лента новостей оставалась неподвижной, а белая панель двигалась вверх-вниз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, тут дело оказалось вот в чем: при раскрытии новости мы создаем блок с размерами экрана и помещаем в него тот блок с картинками и текстом.

Ставим ему `overflow-y: scroll`, а у `<body>` ставим `overflow-y: hidden`.

При закрытии новости возвращаем `<body>` прежнее значение.